# jQuery slideUp slideDown help, it's slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i click a division it will slidUp and if i click that division again it will slideDown.
How can i do this ?

```
$("#id_color_tags").click(function(){
    $("#rightsidefive").slideToggle();
})
```

Tried that but that didn't work.

Comment: That's what I've always used. When you say doesn't work, what exactly do you / don't you see?

Comment: It works perfectly. Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/HvEyR/ otherwise explain **does not works** stuff and show some html,css.

Comment: The functionality of your code is completely unknown unless you include the HTML you are using it on. --- Also, this must be inside a doc ready `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: Voted to close since the OP did not include enough info to solve the problem and now that they've got it working there is no info on what they did - thus the question is useless to keep around on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put an alert in the click event, are you getting to the function?
2. Are the names right.  asp.net can alter names so maybe select on a class name instead.  So `<div class="thisclass">` and the selector then becomes ".thisclass"
3. Same applies for the #rightsidediv

Failing that, post some HTML so we can see.